# Access loop through continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to add a VBA to a command button to look at a text box and if not null, then look at a combo box. If that combo box is null, have a pop up message box. Since it is a continuous form and there are several records showing, it works fine on the first record, however it does not for the following records. I believe this is because I need to loop through each record. Below is the VBA code I have so far. I would greatly appreciate any help regarding the loop, as I am new to VBA.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Text33.Value) Then
    If IsNull(Me.Combo24.Value) Then
        MsgBox "You must state if the rationale is aligned with procedures for each disputed subcategory."
    Else
     'do nothing
    End If
End If

DoCmd.Save
DoCmd.Close
```

Thank  you in advance,

Susan

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Comment: If Not IsNull(Me.Text33.Value) Then If IsNull(Me.Combo24.Value) Then MsgBox "You must state if the rationale is aligned with procedures for each disputed subcategory."

Else 'do nothing End If End If

DoCmd.Save DoCmd.Close

Comment: Sorry but the Ctrl K is not working for me

Comment: You want pop-up message boxes for all rows in your continuous form which could be hundreds or thousands? Does not seem user-friendly! Do it for the current record as user enters data.

Comment: There should only be a maximum of 10 and the idea is they would get one pop up message and fix all the rows.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a continuous form, you can Clone the Form's recordset and loop in each record.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

Dim idx As Integer
For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    If Not IsNull(rs![TextBoxFieldName]) Then If IsNull(rs![ComboBoxFieldName]) Then MsgBox "..."
    rs.MoveNext
Next idx

Set rs = Nothing

With DoCmd
    .Save
    .Close
End With
```

Note in case this is intended for validation purposes, the `DoCmd` actions will always execute regardless of the message-box error/warning.

You can change that by adding an `Exit Sub` after showing the message box.

**Edit:**

---

```
Sub Example()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst

    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        Select Case True
            Case Not IsNull(rs![ComboFieldName]) And IsNull(rs![TextBoxFieldName]):
                MsgBox "You must enter dispute comments for each disputed subcategory."
                GoTo Leave

            Case IsNull(rs![ComboFieldName]) And Not IsNull(rs![TextBoxFieldName]):
                MsgBox "You must state if the rationale is aligned with procedures for each disputed subcategory."
                GoTo Leave

            Case Else:
                'do nothing
        End Select
        rs.MoveNext
    Next idx

    Set rs = Nothing
    With DoCmd
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
    Exit Sub

Leave:
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Kostas. It appears as though it is not working. I do not get any errors however the code does not work. Below is what I have, any ideas?  Private Sub Command301_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

Dim idx As Integer
For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
  
If IsNull(Me.Combo24) = False Then
  If IsNull(Me.Text33) Then
MsgBox "You must enter dispute comments for each disputed subcategory."
Else
End If
End If
Next idx
Set rs = Nothing
With DoCmd
    .Save
    .Close

End With
End Sub

Comment: You need to change `Me.Combo24` and `Me.Text33` with the actual database fields as shown in answer e.g. `rs![FieldName]`. You can find the field name in the `Control Source` property of each control.

Comment: Thank you I will try that now.

Comment: It is still closing the form without any pop up message boxes.

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the Sub and go through the code with F8 to see what it does. Does it loop at all?

Comment: Okay I always thought I was a beginner but now I feel even worse. When I open the Visual Basic for Applications and try to run the code using F8 nothing happens. I believe it is because the line numbers are not visible, and I have been unsuccessful in adding them.

Comment: No panic, we've all been there. Click to the left hand side of the procedure declaration `Private Sub Command301_Click()` to add a red dot. Then run the form and click the button. This will put the procedure in debug mode, where you can advance each line of code with F8.

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like it is not looping through. It works if the first record meets the criteria but if its after the first then it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the subform inside another form?

Comment: It is a continuous form not a subform.

Comment: Can you try the updated answer? I added `rs.MoveLast` and `rs.MoveFirst` - as long as there are records in the form, it should loop.

Comment: OMG Thank you soooo much that works. Is there anyway to not only loop through as above for one if statement but for two if statements. For example:

Comment: If IsNull(Me.Combo24) = False Then
  If IsNull(Me.Text33) Then
MsgBox "You must enter dispute comments for each disputed subcategory."

Else
'do nothing
End If
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.Text33.Value) Then
   If IsNull(Me.Combo24.Value) Then
MsgBox "You must state if the rationale is aligned with procedures for each disputed subcategory."
Else
DoCmd.Save
DoCmd.Close

Comment: See updated answer. Just change the field names again.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Kostas. The update worked perfect.